# Start two servers in one docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a `Dockerfile` with all of my configurations.

At the end I want to run one python server from `python server.py`
And also a node server from `npm start`

Because I can have one `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` how can I start both these two servers when `docker run` executed?

What is the docker recommended way to handle these kind of situations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `supervisord` when you want to run multiple processes in one container - like in your case `npm` and `python server`.

Check [**documentation for supervisord**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) for more information.

I just pick some important parts.

- 1, You will need to install supervisord for docker image

Something like:

```
CentOS: `yum install supervisor`

Ubuntu: `apt-get install -y supervisor`
```

- 2, copy configuration for supervisord (`supervisord.conf`) to docker image
  .

`COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`

In your case `supervisord.conf` should looks like example below (not tested) :

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:npm]
command=npm start

[program:python]
command=python server.py
```

and run `supervisord` as `CMD` command in Dockerfile:

```
...
# install supervisord
# copy supervisord configuration
...
# run supervisord
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: I didn't try this yet, but hope this will work. One last question, can I download this `supervisord.conf` file from my git repository? & then do I have to run this `COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` as well?

Comment: @DilumN Sure. In most cases `supervisord.conf` is alongside `Dockerfile` so you can `COPY` it like in the example. And yes u have to put `supervisord.conf` to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` because `CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]` will take this `conf` file on container startup.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy and light-weight way of doing it.

**Step 1**: Create a script file `runner.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
python server.py &
P1=$!
npm start &
P2=$!
wait $P1 $P2
```

**Step 2**: At the end of your `Dockerfile` , add these lines

```
..
..
COPY runner.sh /scripts/runner.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/runner.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/runner.sh"]
```

It works like cream

**Explanation**:

1. `some_command &` means run some_command and put it in background
2. `python server.py &` means run python server.py and put this process in background.

**Note**: this works with Docker images with **Debian** based base images like Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

So the updated answer would be that now the supervisor can be installed using pip
run `pip install --upgrade supervisor`.    supervisord.conf remains the same as correctly pointed out by @VladoDemcak. and the supervisord can be run by using the `CMD` command

`CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "./path/to/supervisord.conf"]` inside your docker container. `-c` tag is used to specify the path to the conf file.